# How to set header's content type of a Response in a Next js api route

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am using next js 14 app router.
And I want dynamically create an xml file when the api route is called and send it in response.
here is my code:

```typescript
export async function GET(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  try {

    // Set response to XML
    //   res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");


    // Send the XML file to the browser.
     return res.send("my xml string"));

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(err), { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

The compiler dont give an error but when the api is called , it throws an error: res.setHeaders() is not a function

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with last version of NextJS (v14). I was looking to set the `Content-Type` to `application/pdf`. According to the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/headers), we can override (or set) headers (on specific paths if needed) on `next.config.js` file.
I successfully changed the `Content-Type`. This is `my next.config.js` file

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/api/list',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Content-Type',
            value: 'application/pdf',
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

### **UPDATE**

I just found on this [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#cors) about Streaming and NextJS provide this example for set headers on response:

```js
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic' // defaults to auto
 
export async function GET(request: Request) {
  return new Response('Hello, Next.js!', {
    status: 200,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization',
    },
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Next.js API routes, you should use the res.setHeader() method to set the response headers, including the "Content-Type" header for sending XML.

Here's the corrected code for your Next.js API route:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  try {
    // Set the response content type to XML
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

    // Create your XML content (replace this with your actual XML generation logic)
    const xmlString = generateXML(); // Replace generateXML with your XML generation function

    // Send the XML as the response
    return res.send(xmlString);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
}

// Replace generateXML with your XML generation function
function generateXML() {
  // Implement your XML generation logic here
  // For example:
  return '<root><element>Some XML data</element></root>';
}
```

Comment: As i said, i am using app router, this seems to be implementation of page router in next js. For now it is difficult for me  to shift to page router, becuase i have change the whole structure of my app. Although if i didnt find any solution then i must revert back to it but that would take alot more time.